# Why does my log in on webpage not let me log in with correct details?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to make a log in page for my website and it's not letting me log in.

When I use the correct details, it just tells me that I'm using wrong username or password.

Why does this not log me in?

from common.inc.php

```
function logUserIn($username, $password) {
   global $db, $site;
   $out = false;
   $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM wt_users WHERE username = :u");
   $res = $db->prepare($sql);
   if ($res->execute(array(':u'=> $username))) { // MySQL OK
       $details = $res->fetch();
        if ($details) { // Good username
            if (md5($password) == $details['password']) { // good password - we're in!

                $_SESSION['user'] = $details; // Overwrites whatever was there before, which is good
                $_SESSION['user']['status'] = 'loggedin';
                $out = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

from login.php

```
switch (@$_REQUEST['login']) {

case 'logout':
    logUserOut();
    $status = "You have successfully logged out";
    break;

case 'Login':
    if (logUserIn($_REQUEST['username'],$_REQUEST['password'])) {
        $show = 'welcome';
    } else {
        $errors['username'] = 'Either your username or password was incorrect.     Please try again';
        $details['username'] = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $details['password'] = $_REQUEST['password'];
    }
   break;
```

...
from the form

```
if ('form' == $show){
?>
         <h3>Please log in</h3>
         <form method='post' action='<?php echo $site['self']; ?>'>
         <?php echo $errorBlock ?>
         <table>
         <tr><th>Username</th><td><input name='username' value='<?php echo         $details['username'] ?>'/></td></tr>
         <tr><th>Password</th><td><input name='password' type='password' value='<?    php echo $details['password'] ?>'/></td></tr>
         </table>
         <input type='submit' name='login' value='Login'/>
         <input type='submit' name='login' value='Cancel'/>
         </form>
```

I can't see any errors at all. But it is not letting me log in, and it is the correct details from the database I'm using. I know md5 is totally insecure, but I'm just trying to go to basics to get it working. Anyone see any errors off the cuff though?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2 input's with the same name... why submit the form is someone presses cancel? also, both have the same 'name' so the value of $_GET['login'] will always be 'Cancel' ;)

Comment: I'm assunming you mean '$details'? Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There's also an else statement if they cancel, I just tried to make the code more concise.

Comment: add a statement to common.inc.php to output all four values that it's comparing: input user, db user, md5(pw) and db pw.